# Contact mic recording a watch ticking with Arduino

Tags: arduino, contact, contact-mic

Trying to record a ticking sound of watch. Using a piezo contact mic. Want to learn how I can decide what preamp to use and how to match impedance. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Hi and welcome!

Check out Tim Prebble's blogpost on contact mic's:
http://www.musicofsound.co.nz/blog/the-first-rule-of-contact-mic-club

Good luck!

Arnoud

Answer (score 1):

Also guitar pick up are ok for those ticking sounds

Answer (score -2):

PURE ORGANIC SEO FIRM

Chance to save money on search engine marketing, Website Designing/Development

We saved the best promotion for this New year!
ONLY $50!! HuRRy UP!!

Search Engine Optimization– Love your website? Save initial SEO setup fee and see your website on first page of search engines

No Black-hat methods.

Take a trial for just $50 and get linked with 100 quality websites having page rank up to 5.

Our team works directly with you to meet our target which is #1 position on search engines.

We sincerely believe that the above services will merit with the requirements of your Organization.

Get full details now by calling or emailing us.

Answer (score -9):

You know how important it is to be visible.  You know you need to use the internet better.  But you also need to take care of your business.  You can’t do both.  Well, you take care of your business… we’ll take care of the internet for you.  Our expert staff understands how to make search engines your friend.  Email us and we’ll get started.